# I get an error when trying to send to multiple modules using sendDirect

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have to send the same message to multiple modules. I used the following code:

```
cMessage *msg=new cMessage("Broadcast");
msg->setKind(SENDTOALL);

cTopology topo;
topo.extractByModulePath(cStringTokenizer("**.router*.app[0]").asVector());

cTopology::Node *thisNode = topo.getNodeFor(this);

for (int i = 0; i < topo.getNumNodes(); i++) {
if (topo.getNode(i) == thisNode) continue; // skip ourselves


cModule *targetModule =topo.getNode(i)->getModule();

EV_INFO  << "Get Full Name ------------------- "<<i<< topo.getNode(i)->getModule()->getFullPath()<<endl;

sendDirect(msg,targetModule,"in");
```

after sending the message to the first module and trying to send to the next module, I get the following error that the message already scheduled and the simulation stops at this point.

[image]

Can I get any advice? I will be really thankful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The message cannot be sent more than once. To send the same message to many modules, every time *copy* of this message must be created. `dup()` is the convenient method to make a copy, for example:

```
cMessage *copyMsg = msg->dup();
sendDirect(copyMsg ,targetModule,"in");
```

Reference: [Simulation Manual - Broadcasting messages](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:broadcasting-messages)

Comment: That is correct .I did it. Thank you Jerzy for your answers.